# reset auto increment number each year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with `job_no` to be auto increment with the last two digit of the year.

Example: in year `2014` the `job_no` will be like this: `140001`, `140002`, `140003` and it will keep increment until next year which is `2015`, it will reset the count like this: `150001`, `150002`...

it happened that I knew how to merge date with the numbers, but am still unable to figure out how to let it reset yearly.. I will be so thankful for your help and will be glad for a clear view of explanation and examples...

Comment: What job number is assigned to the 10,000th job in a given year?

Comment: Actually, there won't be more than three digit numbers in a year, but in case I added 4 digits. 

The problem is that I need to attach the date with the numbers, because it should be inserted automatically to the table.

I used this method for doing what I have reached so far:

(right(CONVERT([varchar](4),datepart(year,getdate()),(0)),(2))+right('0000'+CONVERT([varchar](4),[Job_No_ID],(0)),(4)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a SQL agent job to run at midnight on December 31 and run the following snippet of code:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('table_name', RESEED, (YEAR(GETDATE()) % 100) * 10000)
```

Note that there are the following problems with this approach:

1. If you put more than 10000 records in the table in a given year then your numbers will run over then end and the year will be wrong
2. You have two different types of information in this column: the identity value and the year.  It is usually better to divide information like that out (i.e., just use an identity column and then also store the date)
3. You only have the year, not the month or day which might be useful in the future if it isn't right now

Comment: Thanks for the help, I followed your advice and am done.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @y INT;
SET @y = YEAR(GETDATE()) % 100; -- or YEAR(@DateOfJob) if you use a variable for that

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @i INT;
SELECT @i = MAX(job_no) FROM dbo.TableName WHERE job_no / 1000 = @y;

SET @i = @y * 1000 + 1 + COALESCE(@i % 1000, 0);

-- if job_no is an IDENTITY column, for some reason:
-- SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TableName ON;
INSERT dbo.TableName(job_no, ...) VALUES(@i, ...);
-- if job_no is an IDENTITY column, for some reason:
-- SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TableName OFF;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: This is going to fail the insert if the job_no_id is an identity column unless you SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.table ON (and then set it off when you're finished)

Comment: @JeffHornby True, I assumed that it was not an IDENTITY column.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks for your help, but using your query, keeps repeating the job_no in every row I insert.

Comment: @user3207594 sorry, couple of minor typos.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set identity inserts and insert a row with the new starting value that you want to use, this will then start inserting from that value.

It kinda goes against database normal forms though as you have two data items in one field.